# Rails - Proper associations/data model for content display "cooldown"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a user model and a content model. When a user views a piece of content, I need to make sure the user does not see that content again for say, 48 hours.

What's the Rails way to model this out? I'd like to have a table with a user_id, content_id, and a timestamp that the view was recorded, then have a worker clear out entries with timestamps > 2 days. This way when a user requests more content, I can filter out content that has an entry where user_id and content_id match.

Don't think it should matter, but I'm using MySQL with Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following in your model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :contents, -> {  where(["EXTRACT(HOUR FROM last_viewed_at) > ? OR last_viewed_at IS ?", 48, nil)}
end
```

I used or condition to make it nil because when it is initialized or new record created so that user can be able to see it.

I am not sure how you are using your worker.

Please suggest me if I am missing anything. I am not intended to answer accurately, rather trying a way I can realize what is possible.